# Contextual filter not working on page

Tags: 8

I have created a view of page and called events (content types) which are showing correctly in Admin/Front then I add contextual filter year which is working correctly if I enter year eg: 2017.
[image]

I have hack template created my own template file (`page--events.html.twig`) and included view `{{ drupal_view('events','page_1') }}`

All events are showing instead 2017 if I hit url drupal.local/events/2017 so here is problem contextual filter not worked on page.

Comment: Maybe you have `Exclude` ticked under `More` in the Contextual filter? Are you saying that filtering is correct in Views Preview, but does the opposite when going through your template?

Comment: yea I am saying that filtering is correct in Views Preview, but does the opposite when going through your template.